# How to filter inside a filter in react

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, filter

I am trying to filter thru an array that show me list of user that don't have a team yet and the other one is they have a team but not the specific team Id that I passed in.

So example when I `console.log(invitees)`:

```
0:
Memberships: Array(1)
0: {teamId: "5413e75f-ff12-4b7a-a3fe-f892cd006366"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
Ratings: []
Skills: []
fullname: "Nhan Nguyen"

1:
Memberships: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
Ratings: []
Skills: [{…}]
fullname: "nick nick"

2:
Memberships: Array(2)
0: {teamId: "4d45c102-0624-4467-ad11-5fa5eaadcf7e"}
1: {teamId: "5413e75f-ff12-4b7a-a3fe-f892cd006366"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
Ratings: []
Skills: []
fullname: "Nhan Nguyen"
```

So right now I am in the teamId `4d4...` and when I try to search users that have not in the team yet or users that already in the team but not in team with id `4d4...`

How can I loop thru that?

Here is my following code:

```
{invitees
  .filter(
    (userTeamId) =>
      userTeamId.Memberships.length < 1 ||
      userTeamId.Memberships.filter((member) =>
        member.temaId !== privateTeamId
      )
  )
  .map((user, index) => (
    <Grid item key={index}>
      <InviteCard tab={tab} user={user} />
    </Grid>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` function on an array expects the predicate function that's passed in to return a true or false result and the call to `filter` then returns an array with the filtered down values.

The inner `filter` isn't really what you're looking to accomplish since you need to return a boolean, not an array. You want to just determine if every value in the member list doesn't match your private team id. For that, you can use the `every` function on an array:

```
{invitees
  .filter(
    (userTeamId) =>
      userTeamId.Memberships.length < 1 ||
      userTeamId.Memberships.every((member) =>
        member.teamId !== privateTeamId
      )
  )
  .map((user, index) => (
    <Grid item key={index}>
      <InviteCard tab={tab} user={user} />
    </Grid>
  ))}
```